# How to migrate parameter store data to other Region / AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

Consider that I have got a AWS account that already has some parameter store data.

Is there a way to migrate these data from this parameter store to another:

- parameter store?
- region?
- AWS account?

I would prefer official tools to do this, but tools similar to dynamoDB dump are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "official tool" to do this. It could be done by iterating through the existing parameters and creating them in the target.

I found this tool that somebody has written: [aws-ssm-copy · PyPI: Copy parameters from a AWS parameter store to another](https://pypi.org/project/aws-ssm-copy/)

It looks like it can copy between Regions and between AWS Accounts (by providing multiple Profiles).

Comment: This is the tool that I was looking for. Maybe I will take some time discovering how to use It, because there is only one example there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://medium.com/@9.one.eight/how-to-migrate-aws-ssm-parameters-e60b0d136805) article might help

For another account, you need to export parameters from account by using command
`aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/" --recursive`

and you will get all the parameters as response.

Now you have to login to another account using command `aws configure`. just replace following values

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

and then follow the article I shared above.